# Long process of OLAP dimensions

Tags: ssis, ssas, olap

I'm looking for a way to optimalize the dimensions in my OLAP Cube. As for now there are 35mil records, 10 dimensions mostly with a key(on recid) and 1-3 attribues and one big dimension with 20 attributes. I did partition my data and optimalized my query as much as I could ( added indexes, passed transformation from cube to dtsx package). But still the dimensions process over 7 hours!

Is there a way to make it better?

Having multiple dimensions with a 2 column key and 1-2 attributes with no hierarchies is actually a pain or good practice?

Edit2: Is it able to partition a dimension?

Answer (score 0):

The first step for optimization would be to see which part of the dimension processing takes how much time. When you process a dimension e. g. form Visual Studio or Management Studio, you see a lot of events in the user interface. This could help you see which part of the processing takes how much  time. This is not easy to see as many processing steps run in parallel.

Some ideas how you can speed up dimension processing:

- You already looked at the relational source side, hence I assume there is not much to gain any more here. Nevertheless, it might make sense to look at the above mentioned details to see the SQL statements executed actually, and see if your optimizations target these.
- In contrast to measure group  processing, dimension processing benefits enormously from enough RAM to keep all dimension data in memory during dimension processing. This means you should run the processing on a machine having enough RAM, and make sure the RAM is available for SSAS and not most of it taken e. g. by the relational engine.
- It might make sense to process the dimensions one after the other instead of all together - especially if you are tight with your RAM. This prevents SSAS from trying o run too many dimension processing jobs in parallel, just ending up with all of them using up RAM, and thus having less RAM available for each dimension.
- Defining relationships  between attributes of the dimension may help speed the processing a bit.
- Speed of the disk does **not** have a lot influence on processing speed once you can keep all dimension data in RAM, as SSAS will then do all processing in RAM, and only write out the data to disk once it is calculated.
- And **no**, you cannot partition dimensions.

Comment: I'm tight on RAM. SQL takes around 100GB and SASS 50GB and there is like 3-5GB free. I run the dimensions in process update in sequentional processing order.

Comment: @Tweene Did you try if a full process of the dimensions is faster? Disadvantage would be that it invalidates all linked measure groups, so you need to process these fully as well. But in total, this may still be faster. Another approach could be to just see if reducing the relational db memory to let's say 50GB and giving 50GB more to SSAS would help. In the end this is a matter of trying and experimenting.

Comment: Actually I changed from sequentional to parallel process and it went from over 6h to 3h but it was just 2 times in a week. No idea why it works that way...